# in git what is the difference between remote add origin vs remote set-url origin

Tags: git

I am doing below on local repo; also clearing remote repos (ie origin):

```
git init
```

Then below, will create 'origin' if it doesn't exist:

```
git remote add origin [repo-url]
```

Else, you can use the set-url subcommand to edit an existing remote:

```
git remote set-url origin [repo-url]
```

Also, you can check existing remotes with

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states for `git remote add <name> <url>`

> Adds a remote named `<name>` for the repository at `<url>`.

and for `git remote set-url <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]`

> Changes URLs for the remote. Sets first URL for remote `<name>` that matches regex `<oldurl>` (first URL if no `<oldurl>` is given) to `<newurl>`.

Simplified if you want to add a remote url use `git remote add <name> <url>` and if you want to update an existing remote name use `git remote set-url <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]`.